# Manage 2 tables with 2 views in the same Joomla backend component

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, components, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm new to Joomla! component developement, and just can't figure out how to do this..

Details:
In my component I should be able to manage two DB tables: Question(id_question, type, text) and each question could have many choices that will be saved in the table Choice(id_choice, text, id_question).

So I found two solutions.. but couldn't really implement any of them since I'm still a beginner and always block at some point, so I'd like to know which one is better and more correct then try to fix the problems :

1/ the main view is the list of questions with add/edit/delete toolbar buttons, when I add a new question the user can fill a form of the question informations and also insert as many choices as he wants (dynamically using javascript/jquery). So when the question is saved using the default save button, I didn't know how to save the choices ! should I use Ajax separatly to do the whole thing, or there's a way to use the default save function for both tables ?

2/ the second solution is something similar to this : http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_categories , the main view contains two submenus one for the questions and one for the choices, each with add/delete/edit buttons.. but even in this solution I didn't know how to manage two view of two different DB tables in the same component!

I hope I explained this clearly, pleaase Help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why they are in different tables Are you saying the answers are reusable in other questions?

Comment: No, they are not reusable for other question.. two tables because there're many possible choices for each question, it's a one-to-many relation